# how to replace middle keyword in url before '?' mark for url re-writing to write in .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

my input url is

> `https://example.com/path/typeX?dataY=mydata`

want output as

> `https://example.com/path/myfile.php?reqType=typeX&dataY=mydata`

Please help me , I am new to url re-writing, my serrver is apache with php installed, thanks in advance.

I tried this

> `RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
>   RewriteRule ^path/([^\.]+)$ path/myfile.php?reqtype=$1&%1`

it is giving correct result on https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ but not working on server, server says the requested url was not found

Comment: Please post the code you are using or have attempted to use to try to create this url.

Comment: please see above code which I tried

Comment: This should not need a RewriteCond to capture the query string contents - you can simply use the `QSA` flag to merge your new query string, with the already existing one, `RewriteRule ^path/([^\.]+)$ path/myfile.php?reqtype=$1 [QSA]`

Comment: If neither works, then check if mod_rewrite is even enabled on the server, and whether you are allowed to use it in your account. Ask your hoster, if you’re not sure.